# Boost serialization unregistered class errors

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, c++11

I cannot seem to get boost::serialization to work well. I have sprinkled the class .cpp files with `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID` macros, after including the class and archive headers, but I still get `unregistered_class` exceptions.

I have looked around and it seems that whatever I can find is 1. either outdated, dealing with old versions of the library, or 2. works only for a simple one-file solution in which all the serializable classes are defined one after the other. Nothing I've found helps.

My solution at present consists of a project, compiled into a static library, that contains the core functionality with the basic archivable classes, and another test project that will eventually be fleshed out into a more concrete logic layer. Getting everything to work with boost::serialization is proving a nightmare. I'm almost tempted to write it myself.

Anyway, the class in question which raises the exception is defined in a header, which looks something like this:

```
#include <boost/serialization/assume_abstract.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
// Other includes...

namespace GameCore { class Component; }
//  Forward declare some boost::serialization functions that appear at the bottom.
// ...
BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT(GameCore::Component);

namespace GameCore
{
    // Some forward declares..

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Base component type.
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class Component : public Updatable, public Object
{
    friend class boost::serialization::access;  

protected:                                  
    template <typename Archive>                 
    friend void boost::serialization::serialize(Archive& archive, Component& object, const unsigned int version);   
    template <typename Archive> friend void boost::serialization::load_construct_data(Archive& archive, Component* t, const unsigned int version);  
    template <typename Archive> friend void boost::serialization::save_construct_data(Archive& archive, const Component* t, const unsigned int version);    

public:
    Component(GameObject& owner);
    virtual ~Component() = 0;

    // Irrelevant stuff..

    GameObject& gameObject;
    Transform* transform;
};
}
//  The component includes have to be placed here because it would otherwise create a cyclic inclusion when trying to compile the 
//  individual component classes, say, Transform, which would end up including itself.
#include "Transform.h"


namespace boost
{
    namespace serialization
    {
        template<class Archive>
        inline void save_construct_data(Archive& archive, const GameCore::Component* t, const unsigned int version)
        {
            archive << t->gameObject;
        }


    template<class Archive>
    inline void load_construct_data(Archive& archive, GameCore::Component* t, const unsigned int version)
    {
        //  Retrieve data from archive required to construct new instance.
        GameCore::GameObject owner;
        archive >> owner;

        //  Invoke inplace constructor to initialize instance of class.
        ::new(t)GameCore::Component(owner);
    }


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //  Serialization function for save/load.
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    template <typename Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& archive, GameCore::Component& t, const unsigned int version)
    {
        archive & boost::serialization::base_object<GameCore::Object>(t);
        archive & boost::serialization::base_object<GameCore::Updatable>(t);
        archive & t.gameObject;
        archive & t.transform;
    }
}
}
```

That is **one** header file. Sorry for the verbosity. Its .cpp file starts like this:

```
#include "Component.h"

#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
// Other includes...

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID(GameCore::Component, "GameCore::Component");

// Class method definitions here.
```

The exception is raised when I try to archive an instance object that **derives** from `Component`, which itself is an abstract class. I'm archiving through a simple method defined in a different manager class:

```
std::ofstream outputFile(fileName);
boost::archive::text_oarchive outputArchive(outputFile);
outputArchive << objects;
```

where `objects` is a `std::list` of `Object`s. `Object` is the base class from which all things, including `Component`s, derive.

I apologize if this sounds convoluted, but there's only three layers of inheritance, and I believe I had a neat and effective architecture before thoughts of serialization crept in.

If you could help me get rid of the irrational `unregistered_class` exceptions I'll light a candle for your souls!

**Update:** Funny thing is, the exception isn't raised for all derived classes of `Component`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After frying my neurones looking for an answer, I stumbled upon this line in the documentation:

> Static Libraries and Serialization
>
> Code for serialization of data types can be saved in libraries just as
>   it can for the rest of the type implementation. This works well, and
>   can save huge amount of compilation time. Only compile serialization
>   definitions in the library. Explicitly instantiate serialization code
>   for ALL archive classes you intend to use in the library. For exported
>   types, only use BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY in headers. For exported types,
>   only use BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT in definitions compiled in the
>   library. For any particular type, there should be only one file which
>   contains BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT for that type. This ensures that
>   only one copy of serialization code will exist within the program. It
>   avoids wasted space and the possibility of having different versions
>   of the serialization code in the same program. Including
>   BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT in multiple files could result in a
>   failure to link due to duplicated symbols or the throwing of a runtime
>   exception.

Splitting `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT` into `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY` and `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT` seems to work.